# Помогите установить кликабельный и не подвижный фон на сайт

Tags: css

Столкнулся с проблемой, не получается установить фон на сайт https://csgosettings.ru

Точнее быть столкнулся с проблемой его пустить ниже меню + придать ему кликабельность

Answer (score -1):

А в чем проблема? повесьте обработчик onClick на тег.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<style>
div
{
width:100%;
 height:50vh;
background:#930;
}
</style>
<body>
<div onclick="alert('Click')">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: К сожалению я не знаю как это сделать(